# Square brackets in ActiveRecord::Migration class name?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In Ruby on Rails 5.2, migration files contain a class that looks like this.

`class MyMigration < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]`

I know that the `[5.2]` syntax is specifying what version of rails the migration targets, but I don't understand how this works. `Migration[5.2]` is not a valid Ruby class name.

What is this square bracket syntax, and how is it not causing ruby syntax errors?

Comment: It isn't a valid class name, but it's a valid method on a class--see also `Hash[]`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ruby objects can have `[]` methods.  They are used in the `Array` class, but any class can implement them.

```
def []()
  ...
end
```

Since classes are full objects, they too can have square bracket methods.

Comment: I see. So that method would return a Class object allowing MyMigration to subclass it?

Comment: @fourseventy It could return anything it wanted, but if it wasn't returning a `Migration` implementation it'd be counter-intuitive.

Comment: @DaveNewton: And if it doesn't return an instance of `Class`, it'll be a `TypeError`.

Comment: @fourseventy: I think the piece of the puzzle you are missing is that you are (wrongly) assuming that the code to the right of `<` has to be a "class name". Actually, classes in Ruby don't *have* names (at least not in the Java sense of the word). A class is simply an object like any other object. So, the code to the right of the `<` is simply *executable Ruby code* that evaluates to an instance of the `Class` class. You could put something like `[Array, Hash].sample` there, and your class would randomly inherit from either `Array` or `Hash`!

Comment: @JörgWMittag That's what all my code does. Makes things more interesting.

Comment: @JörgWMittag Thanks for your comment. It helped me understand something. SO should give an option to bookmark/star comments.